# Choose function from variable

Tags: python

Let's say I have a few functions:

```
def func1(x):
    return x


def func2(x):
    return x**2


def func3(x):
    return x+x
```

I then have some additional code where I would like to pick and choose between the functions, e.g:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

FUNCTION = func1()

y = FUNCTION(x) + 1
z = FUNCTION(x) + 2
m = FUNCTION(x) + 3
```

Something like. Basically I just want to be able to set which function to use one place, and then if I need to use it more than one place, that function will be used, instead of me having to change it multiple places.

Right now the above doesn't work since it needs positional arguments.

So how can this be achieved ?

Comment: What about `FUNCTION = func1`?  You don't want to invoke func1 in the assignment.

Comment: Damn, that was easy. You are right.